# placeholder amazon store windows subsystem for android wsa

Tags: android, windows-11

i have windows 11 22000.258

i installed WSA(windows subsystem for android) and amazon store

when i open amazon store I will receive this message:
"Placeholder app
This package is a placeholder for test purposes. Feel free to uninstall it."

why?

all my friend can use this but I cannot

how can I fix the error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How did you install the Amazon Appstore?

Comment: Amazon app store on Windows 11 is as far as I know at the moment only available for residents in the US. Instead you can try to install Play Store https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-install-google-play-store-windows-subsystem-for-android/

Comment: my location is US

Answer (score 0):

[It's worked for me.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/android/wsa/#troubleshooting-issues-with-amazon-appstore)

1. Select Windows search from the Windows task bar.
2. Search for “Amazon Appstore” and right-click on the Amazon Appstore
   icon.
3. Select “App Settings” in the dropdown options.
4. Select “Storage and Cache” and click both “Clear Storage” and “Clear
   cache”.
5. Go back and select “Force Stop”.
6. Close the Amazon Apptore Settings window.
7. Relaunch the Amazon Appstore.